# Position fixed container with input is going off boundaries

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got a position fixed header, that I want to stay there at all times no matter if I scroll or not. This fixed little header, has a search input inside. The problem is that whenever I open a sidebar on the left, and I push the content with padding-left: XXXpx, this fixed container goes off bounds.

Here's a fiddle:

```css
.wrapper {
  padding-left: 24px;
  padding-right: 24px;
  background-color: #c3c3c3;
  padding-left: 100px;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  background: gray;
  height: 40px;
  position: fixed;
}

.inputText {
  width: 100%;
}

.content {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  widows: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">
    <input class="inputText" type="text" placeholder="Search">
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <span>SOME TEXT</span>
    <span>SOME TEXT</span>
    <span>SOME TEXT</span>
    <span>SOME TEXT</span>
    <span>SOME TEXT</span>
    <span>SOME TEXT</span>
    <span>SOME TEXT</span>
    <span>SOME TEXT</span>
    <span>SOME TEXT</span>
    <span>SOME TEXT</span>
    <span>SOME TEXT</span>
    <span>SOME TEXT</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I achieve the same result without that happening? I could solve it by using a width: calc(100vw - 264px) when I open it. But is this a clean solution?

Comment: you may use overflow hidden for in parent container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `.wrapper` element to have `position:relative` and the `.header` element `position:absolute`. This way, it will stick to the top of the parent element. Also give the `.header` element a `max-width:100%` rule.

Having a `position:fixed` element, will pop-it out of the document flow, so it will always have `width:100%` of the document.

Comment: Also, if you want the header element to stick to the top of the document, you can just use position:fixed and a higher value of z-index, so it will always be at the top of the page content.

Comment: But without position fixed, my header will be scrolled whenever the user scrolls down.

Comment: True. Depends on what is the expected outcome for you. If you want it to always be on top of the document and other DOM elements, use `position:fixed; top:0; left: 0; width: 100%;z-index: 100` and it will stick to the top(z-index value should be set accordingly to your highest existing value in your document). If you want the header to stick to the top of the document, but also move towards right side with the content(when you slide right a sidebar) you can add a class to it, and translate it with a custom x value(as much as your sidebar width).

Comment: Oh ok, so using a calc(100vw - sidebar_width) would be a clean solution?

Comment: Yes. But also see the overflow-x value, as you don't want your document to have "sidebar_width" margin in the right side of it, after expanding the sidebar. (Use overflow-x: hidden), as someone pointed out earlier.

Answer (score 1):

If you give left:0 right: 0 and top:0 to your header, it'll work
The problem here is, you set header's width according to wrapper (100%)
But what you want to do it is, to set width according to page itself